# How to execute a JPA Bulk Update statement which takes a List as a parameter value

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, bulkupdate

I have an Update Query that looks like this

```
UPDATE 
    table_name 
SET 
    column_name = ? 
WHERE
    column_name = ? AND id in (?)
```

So the JPA transaction is

```
em.createNativeQuery(Update_QUERY)
   .setParameter(1, updatedStatus)
   .setParameter(2, currentStatus)
   .setParameter(3, ids)
   .executeUpdate();
```

The Input to the method is List id, currentStatus, and updatedStatus

How do I pass the List as a single parameter, if I convert the List to a comma-separated String I get the error Specified text is not number as strings is not allowed in the In clause.

Comment: why use a "native query" when JPQL does UPDATE also

Comment: I am new to JPQL so could not find a way where I can pass the List of ID , if you have any suggestions please let me know

Comment: as already said ... use JPQL UPDATE, and that supports input a List as a parameter value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do I pass the List as a single parameter

An example approach:

```java
String jpql = "UPDATE NameEntity ne " + 
              "SET ne.valstring = :updated_status " +
              "WHERE ne.valstring = :current_status AND ne.id IN :ids";
em.createQuery(jqpl)
  .setParameter("updated_status", updatedStatus)
  .setParameter("current_status", currentstatus)
  .setParameter("ids", Arrays.asList(ids))
  .executeUpdate();
```

Three simple rules:

1. Use native SQL for bulk update / delete on tables that are **not** mapped to entities.

   Native SQL queries work directly on database tables bypassing the persistence context (a set of managed entities), so it is safe to use such queries if a given database table has no corresponding entity.
2. Use JPQL for bulk update / delete on tables that are mapped to entities

   In case of a given database table is mapped by an entity, using a SQL update / delete will lead to inconsistency between persistence context and the underlying database, so use JQPL counterparts instead and the persistence provider will take care of consistency.
3. Bulk update / delete should be executed as the first operation within the transaction or ideally in its own transaction.

Comment: Since id is declared as int in the NamedEntity for me I get the error parameter value element did not match expected type

Comment: What exactly did you pass to `ids` in `Arrays.asList(ids)` ?

Comment: List<Integer> was passed

Comment: [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) expects an array rather than a collection. If you want to pass List<Integer> then `.setParameter("ids", ids)` would be enough, where `ids` parameter refers to your List<Integer>.

Answer (score 0):

### Setting a List parameter

The JPA [`Query`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) interface [`setParameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method that accepts an `Object` parameter:

```
Query setParameter(String name, Object value)
```

can take a `List` as the parameter value.

This works in the same way for JPQL, Criteria API, or bulk update and delete queries:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createNativeQuery("""
    UPDATE 
        post
    SET 
        status = :newStatus
    WHERE 
        status = :oldStatus AND
        id IN :ids

    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("oldStatus", PostStatus.PENDING)
.setParameter("newStatus", PostStatus.APPROVED)
.setParameter("ids", List.of(1L, 2L, 3L))
.executeUpdate();
```

> For more details about executing bulk update and delete statements with JPA and Hibernate, check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/bulk-update-optimistic-locking/) as well.